# simple jquery image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple jquery image gallery. When a user clicks on thumb it will replace ‘thumb’ to ‘large’ in src attribute of the main Image, I use delegate method of jQuery to dynamically load thumbs and use them without bind event listeners for new thumbs. **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwQGm/)**

Now i need to be able to link to a specific image in the gallery, For example, `example.com/gallery.php#3rdimage` so the user will immediately see the 3rd image in the gallery,  something like the method that engadget is using http://www.engadget.com/photos/samsung-series-5-chrome-os-laptop-vs-11-inch-macbook-air-fight/#4128000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply grab the page's hash value and use it as an index against the set of thumbs:

```
wlh = window.location.hash[1];
if (!isNaN(wlh)) {
    $('#largeImage').attr('src', $('#thumbs img').eq(wlh-1).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'large'));
}
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/EbCKN/show/#3](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/EbCKN/show/#3)** (will initially show the 3rd image)

To add a hash to the URL while browsing images so the URL is primed for sharing a certain image, it's just an extra line after changing the `#largeImage`:

```
window.location.hash = $('#thumbs img').index(this)+1;
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/EbCKN/1/show/](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/EbCKN/1/show/)** ([edit](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/EbCKN/1/))

Comment: +1 Would be nice if the click handler would also update the hash to the number of thumb being selected.

Comment: it's not working with #10 and above. please take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/EbCKN/3/show/#10

Comment: @NL500: See [jsfiddle.net/n7eK5/show/](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/n7eK5/show/) ([code](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/n7eK5/)) for an adjustment to support more than 9 images.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple jquery image gallery!

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".thumb").click(function() {
  var dir = $(this).attr("src");
  $('#image').hide();
  $('#image').fadeIn('fast');
  $('#image').attr("src",dir);
 });
});
```

```css
#image{
border:4px #666 solid;
height:480px;
width:640px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="image" src="http://www.981powerfm.com.au/images/stories/2014/09/happy_animal_5.jpg" border="0"/>

<img src="http://www.981powerfm.com.au/images/stories/2014/09/happy_animal_5.jpg" class="thumb" width='100px' />
<img src="http://smartyvet.com/site/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/happy5.jpg" class="thumb" width='100px' />
<img src="http://www.telegram.ee/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/a.aaa-Happy-animals.jpg" class="thumb" width='100px' />
```

Comment: including a bit of commentary would vastly improve this answer